# jQuery .toggle() to not show/hide all within .on 'click'?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm actually having the same problem like as in [How to prevent jQuery .toggle() to show/hide all within .on 'click'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11348024/how-to-prevent-jquery-toggle-to-show-hide-all-within-on-click) but it didn't help so I'm making my own question.

Is there anyway to prevent toggle to show all but instead show only the neccesary toggle for the user to click? (extra topping -> extra_toppings selected) I did try with my minimum knowledge of using IDs as well `this`, `next()`, `parents()` but with no success.

Here's my code:

#### JavaScript

```
$(".extra_topping").click(function() {
  $(".extra_toppings").toggle('slow');
});
```

#### HTML

(inside a loop over all foods: `@foods.each do |food| ...`)

```
<div class="extra_topping">
  <a>Click Me!</a>
</div>

<div class="extra_toppings">
  <a> Show </a>
</div>
```

I shortened to original HTML to just this to simplify the problem.

Here are my actual code look like : (without the rails code)

```
<table class="table">
  <thead >
  <tr>
    <th>Name</th>
    <th>Price</th>
    <th>Category</th>
    <th>Quantity</th>
    <th>Actions</th>
    <th>Additional Menu</th>
    </tr>
</thead>
<tbody>

  <tr>
    <td>
    </td>
    <td id="food" style="font-weight:bold;">

    </td>
    <td>

    </td>   

    <td>

    </td>
    <td>

    </td>
    <td>
    <div class="extra_topping">
        <a>Click me!</a>
    </div>                      
    </td>
</tr>
<tr class="extra_toppings">
    <td>
    </td>
    <td colspan="4">
        <div class= "mediocre">
            <div class= "xaxixo">
                <h6>Our Additional Menu</h6>
            </div>
            <div class="extra_topping">



            </div>

            <table class="mediocre_table">
            <tr>
                <td>
                    <div class="full_mediocre">

                              <div class="mediocre_collumn">

                              </div>

                </div>
                </td>
            </tr>
          </table>
        </div>
    </td>
    <td>
    </td>   
</tr>

</tbody>
```

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/bYEZH/ Hide 'toggle divs' with css, if i understand your question at all? :)

Comment: Hi,Nevermind. Actually i already achieve jsfiddle.net/bYEZH. I only want to show particular element instead showing it all.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm finally make it work by changing the code from:

```
$(".extra_topping").click(function(){
  $(this).next('.extra_toppings').toggle('slow');
});
```

into:

```
$(".extra_topping").click(function(){
  $(this).parents('tr').next().toggle('slow')
});
```

It Works!

Answer (score 2):

You could use:

```
$(".extra_topping").click(function(){
  $(this).next('.extra_toppings').toggle('slow');
});
```

If that was what your markup always looked like, e.g.

```
<div class="extra_topping">
    <a>Click Me!</a>
</div>       
<div class="extra_toppings">
    <a> Show </a>
</div> 

<div class="extra_topping">
    <a>Click Me!</a>
</div>      
<div class="extra_toppings">
    <a> Show </a>
</div>
```

[**jsFiddle here.**](http://jsfiddle.net/G24aQ/13/)

Comment: Hi Zenith thanks for the answer. I already try recreate it before using (this) and next but with no success..is it because of the table format? since my extra_toppings using tr instead of div as a class

Comment: @MeiSputra The HTML you've provided doesn't show me more than one example of extra_topping and extra_toppings (two extra_topping and one extra_toppings as I count). I can't guess where the elements are located, you need to show me.

Comment: Hi zenith thanks for the reply. I already add the codes which are the real one on the top , below the short example. extra toppings are actually inside a loop and use tr as a class.

Comment: @MeiSputra Can you not just provide me with how it actually ends up looking? What relation does extra_topping have to extra_toppings location wise? I could answer it and help you in one minute if I knew your exact layout or you gave me a jsFiddle :)

Comment: Hi zenith thanks for the help i finally solve the case by using parents() and next().

Comment: Next time try to include everything in your question when you first ask it, you'll get a solution a lot quicker that way